# Simular digitação do teclado programaticalmente em c

Tags: c, teclado

**O problema:**
Eu preciso que meu programa em C escreva como se fosse um teclado. Quando eu abrir o google, por exemplo, e clicar no campo de busca eu gostaria que ficasse aparecendo vários 'a'. Como se a tecla estivesse pressionada no teclado.

**Contexto extra:**
Eu estou fazendo um adaptador bluetooth para um controle de super nintendo. Eu leio os comandos do controle com um microcontrolador MSP430F5529 e mando o resultado via bluetooth (HC-05) pro notebook.
No notebook, eu tenho um programa em C que lê os caracteres que chegam no arquivo /dev/rfcomm0 e dão printf neles. Eu preciso que esse printf() seja reconhecido pelo snes9x.

**Código para ilustrar:**

*Eu tenho seguido por essa linha, e falhado*

```
FILE * fp;
char input;

fp = fopen("/dev/rfcomm0", "rb");

while(1) {
  input = fgetc(fp);
  fputc(input, stdin);
  //printf("%c", input);
}
```

Comment: Você não pode escrever na `stdin` sua, mas se tiver um `pipe` aberto e alguém do outro lado lendo, basta escrever nele

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assumindo que seu teclado se encontra em `/dev/input/event3`, segue um código capaz de "simular" a digitação do comando `ls -al` seguido de um `enter`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <linux/input.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#define KEYBOARD_DEVICE_PATH  "/dev/input/event3"

int simularTecla( uint16_t tecla )
{
    int fd = -1;
    struct input_event k;

    /* Obtem um descritor para o dispositivo (teclado) */
    fd = open( KEYBOARD_DEVICE_PATH, O_WRONLY | O_NONBLOCK );

    if( fd < 0 )
        return -1;

    /* Toma controle exclusivo do teclado */
    if(ioctl( fd, EVIOCGRAB, 1 ))
        return -1;

    /* Pressionando Tecla */
    k.type = EV_KEY;
    k.value = 1;
    k.code = tecla;
    gettimeofday( &k.time, NULL );
    write( fd, &k, sizeof(struct input_event) );

    /* Soltando Tecla */
    k.type = EV_KEY;
    k.value = 0;
    k.code = tecla;
    gettimeofday( &k.time, NULL );
    write( fd, &k, sizeof(struct input_event) );

    /* Liberando controle do teclado */
    ioctl( fd, EVIOCGRAB, 0 );

    /* Fechando descritor para o dispositivo (teclado) */
    close(fd);

    /* Sucesso*/
    return 0;
}


int main( void )
{
    /* Sequencia de teclas */
    uint16_t teclas[] = { KEY_L, KEY_S, KEY_SPACE, KEY_MINUS, KEY_A, KEY_L, KEY_ENTER };
    unsigned int count =  sizeof(teclas) / sizeof(teclas[0]);
    unsigned int i = 0;

    /* Simula sequencia de teclas */
    for( i = 0; i < count; i++ )
        simularTecla( teclas[i] );

    return 0;
}
```

Compilando:

```
$ gcc kbdsim.c -o kbdsim
```

Testando (como root):

```
# ./kbdsim
ls -al
# ls -al
total 32
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Oct 27 02:18 .
drwxrwxrwt. 30 root root 12288 Oct 27 02:18 ..
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root  8760 Oct 27 02:18 kbdsim
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  1287 Oct 27 02:18 kbdsim.c
```

Com uma pequena modificação na `main()`, você pode simular a ativação da tecla `A` uma vez a cada segundo por 100 vezes seguidas:

```
int main( void )
{
    for( i = 0; i < 100; i++ )
    {
        simularTecla( KEY_A );
        sleep(1)
    }

    return 0;
}
```

O mapeamento com o código de cada tecla pode ser encontrado [aqui](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/uapi/linux/input-event-codes.h).

Comment: O código está funcionando. Pórem as teclas só aparecem depois que eu aperto elas 4 vezes. Aí aparecem 4 'a' ou 4 'b'. Queria fazer funcionar tecla a tecla, mas não sei como.

Answer (score -1):

```
FILE* controlador, snes;
char input;

controlador = fopen("/dev/rfcomm0", "rb");
snes = fopen("/dev/snes9x", "a");

while(controlador) {
     input = fgetc(controlador);
     if(snes)
         fputc(input, snes);

}
```

Comment: `snes` não deveria ter sido aberto com `w` ou `a` para permitir a escrita?

Comment: muito bem observado